# Including external jar-files in a new jar-file build with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I have just 'inherited' a Java-project and not coming from a Java-background I am a little lost at times. Eclipse is used to debug and run the application during development. I have through Eclipse succeeded in creating a .jar-file that 'includes' all the required external jars like Log4J, xmlrpc-server, etc. This big .jar can then be run successfully using:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

My next step is to automate builds using Ant (version 1.7.1) so I don't have to involve Eclipse to do builds and deployment. This has proven to be a challenge due to my lacking java-knowledge. The root of the project looks like this:

```
|-> jars (where external jars have been placed)
|-> java
| |-> bin (where the finished .class / .jars are placed)
| |-> src (Where code lives)
| |-> ++files like build.xml etc
|-> sql (you guessed it; sql! )
```

My build.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="Seraph">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>

    <property name="build.dir"     value="bin"/>
    <property name="src.dir"       value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"       value="../jars"/>
    <property name="classes.dir"   value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"       value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="jar.file"      value="${jar.dir}/seraph.jar"/>
    <property name="manifest.file" value="${jar.dir}/MANIFEST.MF"/>

    <property name="main.class" value="no.easyconnect.seraph.core.SeraphCore"/>

    <path id="external.jars">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
        <path refid="external.jars" />
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${build.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cleanall" depends="clean"/>

    <target name="build" depends="init">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}" classpathref="project.classpath">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="build-jar" depends="build">
        <delete file="${jar.file}" />
        <delete file="${manifest.file}" />

        <manifest file="${manifest.file}" >
            <attribute name="built-by" value="${user.name}" />
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />
        </manifest>

        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" 
            basedir="${build.dir}" 
            manifest="${manifest.file}">
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

I then run:
    ant clean build-jar

and a file named seraph.jar is placed in the java/bin/jar-directory. I then try to run this jar using the following command:
    java -jar bin/jar/seraph.jar

The result is this output at the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at no.easyconnect.seraph.core.SeraphCore.<clinit>(SeraphCore.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
Could not find the main class: no.easyconnect.seraph.core.SeraphCore. Program will exit.
```

I suspect that I have done something amazingly silly in the build.xml-file and have spent the better part of two days trying variations on the configuration, to no avail. Any help on getting this working is greatly appreciated.

Oh, and I'm sorry if I left some crucial information out. This is my first time posting here at SO.

Comment: If I were you I would use Maven 2 or Maven 3 instead of Ant, but it would also be a challenge.

Comment: I did manage to fingure out an ok way to accomplish what I wanted. See below for the details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the helpful advice from people who have answered here I started digging into One-Jar. After some dead-ends (and some results that were exactly like my previous results I managed to get it working. For other peoples reference I'm listing the build.xml that worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="<INSERT_PROJECT_NAME_HERE>">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>

    <property name="one-jar.dist.dir" value="../onejar"/>
    <import file="${one-jar.dist.dir}/one-jar-ant-task.xml" optional="true" />

    <property name="src.dir"          value="src"/>
    <property name="bin.dir"          value="bin"/>
    <property name="build.dir"        value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir"      value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.target.dir"   value="${build.dir}/jars"/>
    <property name="external.lib.dir" value="../jars"/>
    <property name="final.jar"        value="${bin.dir}/<INSERT_NAME_OF_FINAL_JAR_HERE>"/>

    <property name="main.class"       value="<INSERT_MAIN_CLASS_HERE>"/>

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${external.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.target.dir}"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${bin.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cleanall" depends="clean"/>

    <target name="build" depends="init">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="${classes.dir}" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>   
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="build-jar" depends="build">
        <delete file="${final.jar}" />
        <one-jar destfile="${final.jar}" onejarmainclass="${main.class}">
            <main>
                <fileset dir="${classes.dir}"/>
            </main>
            <lib>
                <fileset dir="${external.lib.dir}" />
            </lib>
        </one-jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

I hope someone else can benefit from this.

Comment: Hi, old answer, i know, but how should the manifest look for your example? Edit: Got it, one-jar builds it itself.

Answer (score 50):

From your ant buildfile, I assume that what you want is to create a single JAR archive that will contain not only your application classes, but also the contents of other JARs required by your application.

However your `build-jar` file is just putting required JARs inside your own JAR; this will not work as explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) (see note).

Try to modify this:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" 
    basedir="${build.dir}" 
    manifest="${manifest.file}">
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</jar>
```

to this:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" 
    basedir="${build.dir}" 
    manifest="${manifest.file}">
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</jar>
```

More flexible and powerful solutions are the [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) or [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) projects. Have a look into those if the above does not satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Does this extracts the jar and includes the class files in final jar. Its exhibiting same behaviour in my build file. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072253/ant-including-both-jar-files-and-class-files-in-dest-jar).

Answer (score 2):

[Cheesle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305920/cheesle) is right.  There's no way for the classloader to find the embedded jars.  If you put enough debug commands on the command line you should be able to see the 'java' command failing to add the jars to a classpath

What you want to make is sometimes called an 'uberjar'.  I found [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) as a tool to help make them, but I haven't tried it. Sure there's many other approaches.

Comment: Anyone know exactly what Eclipse uses to accomplish this? Up until now Eclipse has been used to build this application and it has always made one neat package with everything included. Would be wonderful to accomplish the same with Ant. Will have a look at one-jar and jarjar to see if I can hook that into the ant-process.

Comment: I have to say that this suggestion of yours was a life-saver for me.  Thanks very much.. it works great!

Comment: I too would like to know how Eclipse does it.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Here's the answer:  When Eclipse builds the jar file, it bundles in a little glue of its own called org.eclipse.jarinjar or something like that.  It's a custom class loader that knows how to extract the needed classes from the embedded jar file.  I expect that one-jar and JarJar do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, either reference the new jars in your classpath or unpack all classes in the enclosing jars and re-jar the whole lot!  As far as I know packaging jars within jars is not recommeneded and you'll forever have the class not found exception!

Comment: I'll just have to believe you on this. My java-fu is not so strong. However I had though that the process was trivial since Eclipse manages to do it right. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Cheesle said, you can unpack and your library Jars and re-jar them all with the following modification.

```
    <jar destfile="${jar.file}"  
        basedir="${build.dir}"  
        manifest="${manifest.file}"> 
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" /> 
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" /> 
    </jar>
```

Jar files are really just zip files with a manifest file embedded.  You can extract and repackage the dependency Jars into your application's Jar file.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html
"The Zip task also supports the merging of multiple zip files into the zip file. This is possible through either the src attribute of any nested filesets or by using the special nested fileset zipgroupfileset."

Do pay attention to the licenses involved with your dependency libaries.  Linking externally to a library and including the library in your application are very different things legally.

EDIT 1: Darn my slow typing.  Grodriguez beat me to it. :)

EDIT 2: If you decide you can't include your dependencies into your application then you have to specify them in your Jar's classpath either at the command line at startup or via the Manifest file.  There's a nice command in ANT to handle the special formatting of the classpath in a Manifest file for you.

```
<manifestclasspath property="manifest.classpath" jarfile="${jar.file}">
    <classpath location="${lib.dir}" />
</manifestclasspath>

 <manifest file="${manifest.file}" >      
        <attribute name="built-by" value="${user.name}" />      
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />    
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}" />
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classpath issue when running an executable jar as follows:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

One way to fix the problem is to set the classpath on the java command line as follows, adding the missing log4j jar:

```
java -cp myfile.jar:log4j.jar:otherjar.jar com.abc.xyz.MyMainClass
```

Of course the best solution is to add the classpath into the jar manifest so that the we can use the "-jar" java option:

```
<jar jarfile="myfile.jar">
    ..
    ..
    <manifest>
       <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.abc.xyz.MyMainClass"/>
       <attribute name="Class-Path" value="log4j.jar otherjar.jar"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

The following answer demonstrates how you can use the [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) to automate the seeting of the classpath manifest entry

[Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)

Comment: This is not what the OP apparently wants. From his build.xml file it looks like he wants to actually include all required jars in the jar file he's generating.

Comment: That's correct Grodriguez. My goal is to let our users download only one file and run that. Having everything contained in one archive makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NetBeans and needed a solution for this also. After googleling around and starting from Christopher's answer i managed to build a script that helps you easily do this in NetBeans. I'm putting the instructions here in case someone else will need them.

What you have to do is download one-jar. You can use the link from here: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant
Extract the jar archive and look for one-jar\dist folder that contains one-jar-ant-task-*.jar, one-jar-ant-task.xml and one-jar-boot-*.jar. Extract them or copy them to a path that we will add to the script below, as the value of the property one-jar.dist.dir.

Just copy the following script at the end of your build.xml script (from your NetBeans project), just before /project tag, replace the value for one-jar.dist.dir with the correct path and run one-jar target.

For those of you that are unfamiliar with running targets, this tutorial might help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-139904.html . It also shows you how to place sources into one jar, but they are exploded, not compressed into jars.

```
<property name="one-jar.dist.dir" value="path\to\one-jar-ant"/>
<import file="${one-jar.dist.dir}/one-jar-ant-task.xml" optional="true" />

<target name="one-jar" depends="jar">
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
<property name="src.dir"          value="src"/>
<property name="bin.dir"          value="bin"/>
<property name="build.dir"        value="build"/>
<property name="dist.dir"         value="dist"/>
<property name="external.lib.dir" value="${dist.dir}/lib"/>
<property name="classes.dir"      value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.target.dir"   value="${build.dir}/jars"/>
<property name="final.jar"        value="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
<property name="main.class"       value="${main.class}"/>

<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${external.lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<mkdir dir="${bin.dir}"/>
<!-- <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/> -->
<!-- <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/> -->
<mkdir dir="${jar.target.dir}"/>
<copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${classes.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>

<!-- <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/> -->
<javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="${classes.dir}" source="${source}" target="${target}">
    <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>   
</javac>

<delete file="${final.jar}" />
<one-jar destfile="${final.jar}" onejarmainclass="${main.class}">
    <main>
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </main>
    <lib>
        <fileset dir="${external.lib.dir}" />
    </lib>
</one-jar>

<delete dir="${jar.target.dir}"/>
<delete dir="${bin.dir}"/>
<delete dir="${external.lib.dir}"/>

</target>
```

Best of luck and don't forget to vote up if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of functionality that is already built in to the ant jar task.

If you go to [The documentation for the ant jar task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) and scroll down to the "merging archives" section there's a snippet for including the all the *.class files from all the jars in you "lib/main" directory:

```
<jar destfile="build/main/checksites.jar">
    <fileset dir="build/main/classes"/>
    <restrict>
        <name name="**/*.class"/>
        <archives>
            <zips>
                <fileset dir="lib/main" includes="**/*.jar"/>
            </zips>
        </archives>
    </restrict>
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.acme.checksites.Main"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

This *Creates an executable jar file with a main class "com.acme.checksites.Main", and embeds all the classes from all the jars in lib/main.*

It won't do anything clever in case of namespace conflicts, duplicates and things like that. Also, it will include all class files, also the ones that you don't use, so the combined jar file will be full size.

If you need more advanced things like that, take a look at like [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) and [jar jar links](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)