# Ant including both jar files and .class files in dest jar

Tags: java, ant, build, jar, executable-jar

I have defined a jar task using ant `build.xml`. I need to bundle all the dependencies into my jar. I don't understant why ant extracts the jars and includes both `.jar`s and `.class` files into my jar. It unnecessarily increases the size of my jar file. Here is my jar task.

```
<jar destfile="build/main/ERS2SupportingUtilities.jar">
            
            <fileset dir="target/classes">
                <exclude name="*.sh"/>
            </fileset>

            <restrict>
             <name name="**/*.class"/>
             <archives>
               <zips>
                 <fileset dir="./src/main/resources/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/> 
               </zips>
             </archives>
            </restrict>

            <manifest>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.cibc.ers2.invoker.JobTest"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.3RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/junit-4.7.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.orm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
                                                    ./lib/HashUtility.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
                                                    ./lib/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
                                                    ./lib/ojdbc14.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
                                                    ./lib/spring-batch-test-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.oxm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/commons-beanutils.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.binding-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./lib/org.springframework.test-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
                                                    ./launch-context.xml
                                                    ./log4j.xml"
                />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
```

I have also tried `zipgroupfileset` but that also is giving the same problem.

### EDIT

Apologies for not giving enough info about what I am trying to achieve. I have got an application which I am compilint @ `target/classes`. I need to package this application including my class files and dependecies into one jar.

Comment: why do you need restrict tag?

Comment: Uh, you are specifically including classes, with the first fileset you included in your JAR task.

Comment: You didn't tell us what you are trying to achieve. To include only jars?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I want to include only jars.

Comment: but in edit you say you want to include classes and jars. " I need to package this application including my class files and dependecies into one jar."

Comment: I am really sorry for all the confusion. 

1) I want to include **my application's classes** 
2) and dependent jars. I don't want to include dependent jars' classes, I want to include them as jars only.

Comment: so what is the path to dependant jar's classes and dependants jars?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fileset dir="target/classes">
     <exclude name="*.sh"/>
 </fileset>
```

includes all files from target/classes which are not shell scripts.

```
<restrict>
    <name name="**/*.class"/>
    <archives>
         <zips>
             <fileset dir="./src/main/resources/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/> 
          </zips>
     </archives>
</restrict>
```

It seems like you again include classes and jars here.

If you want only jar change all above to :

```
<zipfileset dir="./src/main/resources/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
```

Comment: the first `<fileset>` is for including only my application classes. I don't have any dependencies as classes. If I remove `fileset` and `restrict`, how will ant know where are my application classes?

Comment: @juzerali, again make sure what you want to include, classes and dependency jars or only jars, or only classes. And finally show to us the project structure.