# Importing Jar files in another directory within your jar file

Tags: java, jar, import

I have a Jar file that has the a few packages.

I want to import the commons library and within Eclipse that's pretty simple.

However when I export the jar file, and run it, it is not able to find the commons library and therefore unable to run. I want to know if I have to move the commons jar files to the exact same directory (within the package)? Or if there is something I can add to the import lines to make it work?

I also want to make this jar file able to be sent to people and used by anyone without having to get them to modify anything on their computer

Comment: you need to add it to your classpath

Comment: please show how you are trying to run your program

Answer (score 0):

you need to include jars in your classpath if you are running on command line ([Here is an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar))

if you want it to all be neatly wrapped in one jar consider looking at [OneJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770071/including-external-jar-files-in-a-new-jar-file-build-with-ant). ([oneJar example](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/java-one-jar-example-using-ant-and.html)) or JarJar.