# Ant: how to create <jar> that includes files from <path>?

Tags: ant, jar, path, uberjar

Given an Ant `path` element like the following one:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${common.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${servlet.jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="${j2ee.jar}"/>
    ...
</path>
```

How can I create an uber-`jar` that includes all the files in the `path` without having to spell out all the file names again? The following works, but contains duplicate code, and is not what I want:

```
<jar jarfile="uber.jar" ...>
    <manifest> ... </manifest>
    <zipfileset src="${common.jar}"/>     // UNWANTED code duplication
    <zipfileset src="${servlet.jar}"/>
    <zipfileset src="${j2ee.jar}"/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
<jar destfile="über.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${entry.point.class}"/>
    </manifest>
    <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
</jar>
```

I don't understand why the `common.jar` would have *unwanted duplicate code*. Also, you normally don't include jars inside a jar.

I think what you really want to create is a [War File](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html). A war file can contain multiple jars, plus the classes you want to execute (the ones you compiled via the `<javac>` task). In the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, you include a `Main-Class:` entry pointing to the class that should be the entry point of your war. Users will be able to execute your war as:

```
 $ java -jar my.war
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like the line `<path refid="compile.classpath">` to avoid listing all the jars, actually about 20 in my case, for a second time (that's the code duplication i meant).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create an executable jar with the classpath listed inside the manifest file:

- [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)