# How to set manifest tag for jar file in build.xml?

Tags: xml, ant, build, jar, manifest

I want to make a build.xml for ant build.

I have the directory structure like this

```
practice
|____src
|    |_____Func1.java
|    |_____Func2.java
|    |_____MainClass.java
|
|
|____build
     |_____temp
     |_____hello.jar
```

This `build directory` is not present initially. I want to make a `ant build` which compiles from `src` and put `.class` files in `build/temp`. Then make `.jar` from the `.class` files in `build directory`, and finally `delete` the `temp directory`.

I am able to do these, but the jar file needs `Main-Class`.

The `.jar` creation part is like following

```
<property name="build.dir" value="build"></property>
<property name="temp.dir" value="${build.dir}/temp"></property>

<jar destfile="${build.dir}/${jar.name}.jar" basedir="${temp.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MainClass"/>
        <attribute name="Class-path" value=""/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

I'm not getting what should be the `Class-path`, as all `.class` will be deleted from `temp directory`. I also tried giving the value as the `.jar` file itself.

I'm new to ant build.  So maybe I'm missing something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class path entry in the manifest file is optional, but useful when your code depends on other jars.

For more detailed example, see:

- [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)