# Apache ant manifestclasspath -- how to prevent a jarfile directory catch-22?

Tags: java, ant, classpath

The short of it is: how do I make sure my build directory gets created *before* the `jarfile` argument of the `<manifestclasspath>` tag checks for it? I am using ant 1.9.2.

Here's a minimal example, which will fail unless I create the `build` directory ahead of time:

```
 <path id="master-classpath">
      <pathelement path="src"/>
      <pathelement location="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
 </path>


 <manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar">
    <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
 </manifestclasspath>


<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>


<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false" >
           <src path="src"/>
           <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
      </javac>
</target>


<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloWorld"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.list}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>


<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

The directory for my jar file, of course, is my build directory. And my build directory does not exist before I build. Each subdirectory of the build directory is created by the appropriate target--`compile` calls `mkdir` on the `classes` directory, `jar` creates the `jar` directory. I think this is all pretty standard.

Now here's the thing: the `<manifestclasspath>` tag gets read in before any tasks, because it loads in a variable. So the other targets haven't run yet. And because the directories are missing, the targets *never* run--I have to manually create the `build/jar` directory before running ant, and that's pretty stupid.

Of course, it's no big deal to create the `build` directory ahead of time. But it definitely makes it a little harder if people are trying to install my software themselves. And anyway, the build never exists before you build it! What am I supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use the manifestclasspath task in the target that creates the jar file.

See the following example:

- [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)