# Can not run main() from jar file using ant <java>

Tags: ant, jar, guava

I can't run the main() present in a jar file in my projects lib/ directory.

The ant target is :

```
<target name="testTarget">
    <java jar="lib/test-jar-1.1.jar" fork="on" />
</target>
```

The exception trace is :

```
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 [java] Could not find the main class: com.test.framework.startup.Startup. Program will exit.
 [java] Exception in thread "main" 
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

I already have the guava in my claspath

```
<pathelement location="lib/guava-14.0.jar" />
```

Please help me fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the classpath or the classpathref to your java task.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: I added 'classpathref="classpath">' to the java task.
And the classpath is the id for all classpath entries in my project.
And now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Executable jars pick up their run-time classpaths from their manifest files.

The following answer gives an example of how to build an executable jar:

- [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)