# JAR File NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, build.xml

I am trying to build a runnable JAR file of a project by using build.xml file and the prompt code

```
    cd <the directory of you application>
    ant -f bin/build.xml jar
```

But I have exceptions when I run the JAR because I cannot add the external JAR.

the build.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!--

                    This file was generated by Jason 1.3.9-alpha
                    http://jason.sf.net

                    Ocak 11, 2014 - 01:09:12
-->

<project name   ="virtualClassroom"
         basedir=".."
         default="run">

    <property name="mas2j.project.file" value="virtualClassroom.mas2j"/>
    <property name="debug" value=""/> <!-- use "-debug" to run in debug mode -->
    <property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/bin/classes" />

    <property name="jasonJar" value="C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\MasterThesis-BDI\Jason-1.3.9\Jason-1.3.9\lib\jason.jar"/>
    <property name="JavaCsBridgeJar" value="C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\MasterThesis-BDI\virtualClassroom\lib\JavaCsBridge.jar"/>

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${JavaCsBridgeJar}"/>
        <pathelement location="${jasonJar}"/>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" >  <include name="*.jar" /> </fileset>
    </path>


    <!-- tasks the user can override in his/her c-build.xml script -->
    <target name="user-init">
    </target>
    <target name="user-end">
    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <antcall target="user-init" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <condition property="srcdir" value="${basedir}/src/java" else="${basedir}" >
            <available file="${basedir}/src/java" />
        </condition>
        <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true" optimize="true" includeantruntime="false" >
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <delete file="${ant.project.name}.jar" />
        <copy file="${jasonJar}" tofile="${ant.project.name}.jar" />
        <copy file="${JavaCsBridge}" tofile="${ant.project.name}.jar" />
        <copy file="${mas2j.project.file}" tofile="default.mas2j" />
        <jar update="yes" jarfile="${ant.project.name}.jar" >
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="**/*.asl" />
                <include name="**/*.mas2j" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                  <attribute name="Main-Class" value="jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <delete file="default.mas2j" />
    </target>


    <target name="jnlp" depends="jar" >
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${ant.project.name}-jws"/>
        <java classname="jason.infra.centralised.CreateJNLP"
              failonerror="true" fork="yes" dir="${basedir}/${ant.project.name}-jws" >
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
            <arg line="${ant.project.name} ${mas2j.project.file}"/>
        </java>
        <copy todir="${basedir}/${ant.project.name}-jws" failonerror="no">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="${ant.project.name}.jar" />
            <fileset dir="C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\MasterThesis-BDI\Jason-1.3.9\Jason-1.3.9/src/images" includes="Jason-GMoreau-Icon.jpg" />
        </copy>
        <signjar jar="${basedir}/${ant.project.name}-jws/${ant.project.name}.jar" alias="jason" 
            storepass="rbjhja" keypass="rbjhja" keystore="C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\MasterThesis-BDI\Jason-1.3.9\Jason-1.3.9/src/jasonKeystore" />
        <echo message="**" />
        <echo message="** Java Web Start application created in directory ${ant.project.name}-jws" />
        <echo message="** Update the codebase (in the second line of the .jnlp file)" />
        <echo message="** with the URL where you will upload the application." />
        <echo message="**" />
    </target>   


    <target name="run" depends="compile" >
        <echo message="Running project ${ant.project.name}" />
        <java classname="jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS"
              failonerror="true" fork="yes" dir="${basedir}" >
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
            <arg line="${mas2j.project.file} ${debug} "/>
            <!-- jvmarg line="-Xmx500M -Xss8M"/ -->    
        </java>
        <antcall target="user-end" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean" >
        <delete failonerror="no" includeEmptyDirs="true" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </delete>
    </target>



</project>
```

Do anyone know what to do?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to tell us exactly which class is giving a `NoClassDefFoundError`
As a generic answer, the explanation is that the particular class was available during compile time but missing during runtime. This is a common issue with jar executables.

Solution : Either include the missing classes in the jar itself or add those to the system classpath.

Comment: Hello, I am getting NoClassDefFoundError for the JavaCsBridge.jar that I am trying to add. How can I add this jar file to the system classpath? I am a little bit confused about classpath

Comment: I included all the classes in the jar and the problem solved but I couldn't be able to do it if I didn't have the source code.