# How to jar a Jason Application with Jade Infrastructure

Tags: ant, jar, agent, build.xml, agents-jade

I've developed a Multi Agent System application with the Jason agent platform which also uses the Jade agent framework for its infrastructure. The project works fine with Eclipse. However, I want to create a jar file of the project but since it's not a Java application, it does not have a main class. At [Jason's FAQ Web Page](http://jason.sourceforge.net/faq/faq.html#SECTION00055000000000000000), they've given three options for "How to run my application without JasonIDE" with the third option being the one for creating the jar file:

```
cd <the directory of you application>
ant -f bin/build.xml jar
java -jar <your application>.jar
```

I've gone through the first two steps and the jar file is created successfully. But when I try to run the jar file as stated at the third step, I get the message "Storing configuration C:\Users\Ali.jason\user.properties" at the console and the "Jason Configuration" window pops up.

I've read a lot about creating jar files, but they are all for Java applications with main classes. The closer I got for a Jason application (the only one) was here [at another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057420/jar-file-noclassdeffounderror) which has a problem about the second step of the same code. I've updated my build.xml file according to it, to contain the "Main-Class" info, with the difference being:

```
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="jason.infra.jade.RunJadeMAS"/>
</manifest>
```

which is my case with the Jade infrastructure, instead of the centralised infrastructure there:

```
<manifest>
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS"/>
</manifest>
```

This time, the jar file is created successfully again, but when I try to run it, I got the following message at the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jade/core/ProfileImpl
>   .......
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jade.core.ProfileImpl

"jade.core.ProfileImpl" is not stated at the build.xml file explicitly and I already have the jade library at the build.xml file:

```
<pathelement location="C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Project\jade\lib\jade.jar"/>
```

"jade.jar" is also already in the system path and classpath. I've searched for this problem, but could not find anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It is a quite old question since Jason and JaCaMo are using Gradle now I think it can be easier solved with Gradle.