# Modify Manifest.mf classpath using Ant

Tags: netbeans, ant, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

I need help to modify the classpath in my JAR manifest.mf file. Here's my scenario:

I am trying to make Netbeans build multiple JAR files for this project. I managed to create an Ant target that build the various JAR files. I used ***ant-contrib***'s ***for*** task and Netbeans built-in ***-pre-jar*** target:

```
<property name="multipleJar.basePackage" value="com.mycompany.myproject"/>
<property name="multipleJar.baseDirectory" value="com/mycompany/myproject"/>

<target name="-pre-jar">
    <!-- Packing mutiple jars -->
    <dirset dir="build/classes/${multipleJar.baseDirectory}" includes="*" id="elementid"/> 
    <for list="${toString:elementid}" delimiter=";" param="filename"> 
        <sequential>
            <delete file="dist/multiple/lib/${multipleJar.basePackage}.@{filename}.jar"/>
            <jar destfile="dist/multiple/lib/${multipleJar.basePackage}.@{filename}.jar" 
                filesetmanifest="skip"
                basedir="build/classes/"
                includes="**/${multipleJar.baseDirectory}/@{filename}/*">
            </jar>
        </sequential> 
    </for>
</target>
```

The JAR generation seems OK, but now i have to modify the **Manifest.mf** file on the **MAIN jar**, so these new (dynamically generated) jar files are included in the ClassPath.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [manifestclasspath](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) ANT task.

For an example see:

- [Cannot find Main Class in File Compiled With Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290)